# Smoothness as a topological property

Tags: topological-groups

Motivation: 
Let $G$ be an $\ell$-group (locally profinite group).  A map $G\to \mathbb{C}$ is called smooth provided that it is continuous as a map $$G\to \mathbb{C}_{discrete}.$$This gives us the correct notion of smoothness for $\ell$-groups.

Question: Can we characterize smoothness topologically in other interesting cases, or 
is this just a coincidence?

Comment: What you have written so far is a definition of smooth functions from $G$ to $\mathbb{C}$.  I can easily believe that this is a useful definition for p-adic representation theory.  But where is the characterization?  In particular, do you have some *a priori* definition for smoothness in a topological group?  

Comment: Well, no, that's what I was trying to ask.  Do you have a suggestion for me to rewrite the question better?

Comment: @Marty: If you want to answer the question with that answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @fpqc: Done.  My comment is erased and my comment is the answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question is a bit awkward, as Pete suggests. First, no need to take an $\ell$-group; an $\ell$-space is the right way to start. Second, you've stated the definition of the word "smooth" in this context. Definitions can't be "correct" -- but the word "smooth" is a good choice in this context, because of some parallels between harmonic analysis on p-adic groups and harmonic analysis on real Lie groups.

I think you should put this question aside for a bit.. look at Ralf Meyer's "Smooth Group Representations on Bornological Vector Spaces" to see an answer to something like your question.

Answer (score 1):

We won't be able to do it for varieties, at least, because a cusp is topologically the same as a smooth point (cuspidal cubic and $\mathbb{P}^1$ are homeomorphic, even over $\mathbb{C}$ in the analytic topology).